# Why am I getting an error of unhashable type:'list' in the following code.

Tags: python

I was trying to make the wordcount program. 
But, I am getting stuck on it. Please check what is the fault, i have also marked the error line.

```
def print_words(filename):
  f=open(filename,'rU')
  text=f.read()
  count={}
  for var in text:
    var=var.lower()
    var=var.split()
    if not var in count: // Error Line
      count[var]=1
    else:
      count[var]=count[var]+1
  return count
```

Thanks

Comment: `var.split()` returns a list which is unhashable type so can't be used as a key in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Because `var` is a list and you are trying to use it as a key in a dictionary.

Lists are unhashable because they are mutable.

Turn `var` to a tuple (`tuple(var)`) or re-think your code.

Answer (score 0):

List is a mutable type which cannot be hashed. Refer [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#hashable) from which I am quoting the relevant part

> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
>   member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no
>   mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are.

A non hashable type cannot be used as a dictionary key but in your case [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) generates a list which you are trying to use as a key. A simple solution would be to convert it to a non mutable sequence like tuple

```
count[tuple(var)]=1
```

As there are multiple cases where you have used var as-is, it is recommend to wrap it with a tuple built-in to convert it as a tuple before using it as a key to a dictionary

```
var=tuple(var.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `count` is a dictionary. And finally, `var` is a list.

```
if not var in count:
```

This line checks if a list exists among the dictionary keys. But a list isn't hashable because you can mutate it. But hashability is a prerequisite of being a dictionary key.  That's why the error.

Error regeneration:

```
>>> a=[1,3,4]
>>> b={}
>>> a not in b
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

You can solve it this way:

```
def print_words(filename):
    with open(filename,'rU') as f:
        count={}
        for line in f:
            for word in line.lower().split():
                if word not in count: 
                    count[word] = 1
                else:
                    count[word] += 1
     return count
```

Answer (score 0):

you convert var to list: `var=var.split()`. so you can use `in` for checking. instead you should use `for`.

Also It's better to use `defaultdict` for this jobs.

```
from collections import defaultdict
...
count=defaultdict(int)
for var in text:
    var=var.lower()
    for intem in var.split():
        count[item]+=1
print count
```